# tensorflow js posenet model in web worker using wasm

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I would like to use the `posenet` model inside web worker using `wasm`. There is already an example of pre-trained posenet model provided for a regular `WebGL` model on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet). However I don't know how to use this example with `wasm` and `web worker`. I am trying to figure this out. I understand for `WebGL` you need off-screen canvas enabled for `web worker`. I think `wasm` would be the next best thing to use with `posenet`. If I can't use the example provided can you provide a similar example code using `wasm`?

Comment: Also I m  a noob to tensorflow js so any code starter would be appreciated or link to where to look.

Comment: this was recommended but does answer how to use tensorflow wasm. https://www.sitepen.com/blog/using-webassembly-with-web-workers/

Comment: I am actually running webpack with workerize-loader which allows me to import modules. In other words, I should be able to import tfjs and also use setwasm as provided by official docs example but it did not work. The article you provided to seems to point to loading the tfjs on the main thread and then sending it to the web worker. Is this this is the only way possible?

Comment: in other words I tried using:

Comment: ```import * as posenet from '@tensorflow-models/posenet';
import { setWasmPath } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';

import wasmPath from '../../../node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm/dist/tfjs-backend-wasm.wasm';```

Comment: if you have something like https://github.com/mbasso/wasm-worker; how do I initialize this for tfjs?